# Multi-valued model checking (reduction method)

Tags: reduction, model-checking

Is there any model checking tool already used with examples for multi-valued model checking using the reduction method from multi-valued to classical model checking?

Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you! I am in my first steps working on multivalued model checking where the verifier (model checker) gives a truth values of the formula over "lattice" i.e. the verification result is not only (T,F) but (truth degree) between {T,F}. As of my knowledge there is no tool for preforming the (direct) multi-valued model checking, instead, reduction methods are used to reduce the model checking problem from multi-valued to classical model checking. I am looking for an example of this reduction method that already used with one of the model checkers such as NuSMV, MCMAS. Thanks